# What is $(-8)^\frac{2}{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am comfuse about something.

I want to compute $(-8)^\frac{2}{3}$

Is it $(-2^3)^\frac{2}{3}$=$(-2)^{3\cdot\frac{2}{3}}$=$(-2)^2=4$ ?

Is there any problem here because the base is negative?

Thanks.

Comment: but my Transitions are ok? i mean i could do: $(-16)^3$ which is negative but $(-4^2)^3=(-4)^6$ which is positive.

Comment: @ruth: $(-4^2)^3\not=(-4)^6$, however, it is $-4^6$.

Comment: but $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$

Comment: so i dont get it. because then my answer should be $-4$

Comment: The rule $(a^b)^c$ actually means $[(a)^b]^c$, so $(-4)^6=[(-4)^2]^3$.  Also note that, by convention, $-a^b$ is understood to mean $-(a^b)$ and *not* $(-a)^b$.

Comment: Upon reconsideration, I would say I agree it is 4.

Comment: I don't believe the correct answer is 4.  I believe it is -4. Please see my answer below as to why.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/940673/1508) is a related (but different) question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$(-8)^{\dfrac23}=\left[(-8)^2\right]^{\dfrac13}=(64)^{\dfrac13}=(4^3)^{\dfrac13}$$

$=4\cdot w$ where $w$ is a [cube root](http://www.ilovemaths.com/3demoiver.asp) of unity

Comment: isn't the answer is just $4$? or there are more answers (complex)

Comment: @ruth, If $x=\sqrt[3]{64},x^3=64$ and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalTheoremofAlgebra.html says  "a polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ root"

Comment: @ruth, See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value#Complex_argument and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch

Comment: ok but here it's not $X^3=64$ but $x=\sqrt[3]{64}$ so there is just one value which is $4$ i cant see why it's $4\cdot w$. in your link they say that $w=\frac{-1+\sqrt3i}{2}$

Comment: @ruth, $w$ can be any one of all the three values

Comment: so all other answers here are incomplite.

Comment: @ruth, All the three values are legitimate

Comment: i would glad if you could see why i got the right answer if my transitions were wrong.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee. I think there is a point you should discuss here because I think it is very imoprtant. If you input the expression in WA or other CAS, you get $\cdots$ $-2+2 i \sqrt{3}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I think the principal value of $\sqrt[3]1=1$. I'm not sure why CAS or WA say that.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee. This is a very common situation. In fact, I heard that Mathematica contains now a cube root function.

Comment: I don't agree that $64^{1/3}$ has three values. The cube root of a real number is understood to be a real number, unless there is a specific reason to think otherwise. (If not, where do you stop? What about quaternions, octonions,...?)

Comment: For being the accepted answer, I find this very badly stated and confusing. You seem to be saying that the original expression does not have one value, which means it is not well defined; this should be made clear. Also applying the law of exponents with negative base is well known to be not allowed, at the risk of getting contradictions. Finally $64^{1/3}$ means $\sqrt[3]{64}$ (certainly at the maturity level of OP) which _does_ have a well defined value. I vote $(-1)^{6/2}$.

Answer (score 6):

Your answer is correct.

$(-8)^{2/3}=\left((-8)^{1/3}\right)^2=(-2)^2=4$

$(-8)^{2/3}=\left((-8)^2\right)^{1/3}=(64)^{1/3}=4$

Comment: The answer of lab bhattarcharjee is better.

Comment: No, your answer is much better.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at:
[How do you compute negative numbers to fractional powers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers)

With rational exponents for negative numbers you are in trouble.
You can do $x^{1/3}$ but if you try the thing you want then there are problems. You find that it
depends on the order how you perform the operations resp. which root you choose.
Therefore if we consider only real numbers, such things as $(-8)^{2/3}$ are not well defined. See also:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents

here is the example from this site:
$−27 = (−27)^{((2/3)⋅(3/2))} = ((−27)^{2/3})^{3/2} = 9^{3/2} = 27$

Comment: In general, powering then root extraction is not commutative with root extraction then powering. It matters which operation is done first. 

However, positive real bases are a special case for which this is commutative. When the root being extracted is odd, it is commutative for all real numbers. 

I explain here.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4864176/928654

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You are right. Or you can trace in this way:

$=\sqrt[3]{(-8)^2}=\sqrt[3]{64}=4$

Comment: see my last comment

Comment: @ruth: $(-4^2)^3\not=(-4)^6$, however, it is $-4^6$.

Comment: then why my answer isn't $-4$

Comment: Look at my answer. The writer of the question somehow assumes that you should take the negative square root, but this is not justified.

Answer (score 0):

As $2$ and $3$ are coprime integers, riaising to the ($\frac23$)th power (equivalently, taking the ($\frac32$)th root, is esdsentially squaring and cubing.

While generally, using the simple $p$th power then $q$th root to calculate the ($\frac pq$)th power generally works for only positive real bases, it works in the case of negative numbers for a $(\frac23$)th power.

$$\sqrt[3]{(-8)^2}=\sqrt[3]64=2$$

$$(\sqrt[3]{(-8)})^2=(-2)^2=2 $$

This does not seem to work for all exponents.

$$\sqrt{(-1)^3}=\sqrt{-1}=i$$

if $i^2=-1$

However,

$$(\sqrt{-1})^3=i^3=-i\neq-1$$

But why?

Let us look at the numerator and denominator.

We were taking a square root, which is an even root, in this example. In the $(-8)^{\frac23}$ example, we were taking a cube root, which is an odd root.

Anbd here we have it. For all nonzero integers $z$, none of the $2z$th roots of negative real numbers are real numbers.

But for a ($2z+1)$th root, every real number, including negative numbers, has a unique real root. It follows that for integers $z_1$ and $z_2$, and negative real numbers $-r$,

$$(-r)^{\frac{z_1}{2z_2+1}}=\sqrt[\frac{2z_2+1}{z_1}]{-r}=\sqrt[2z_2+1]{(-r)^{z_1}}=(\sqrt[2z_2+1]{(-r)})^{z_1}$$

has a unique real value, and powering then root extraction yields the same value as root extraction then powering.